# Passing php variable to Google Chart

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli, charts

I have a simple pie chart from official Google Chart gallery page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
          var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
            ['Target',    10],
            ['Achieved',      2], 
          ]);

          var options = {
            title: ''
          };

          var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

          chart.draw(data, options);
        }
      </script>
```

Now I want to pass it only 2 variables `target` and `achieved`. These 2 values are coming from database, how do I pass it to the charts? I can't calculate them before html tag as they are in a loop and generating divs in loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed PHP and JavaScript interchangeably.

You have to first fetch data from database.

Then assign it using:

```
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
            ['Target',    '<?php echo $targetFromDatabase;?>'],
            ['Achieved',      '<?php echo $achievedFromDatabase;?>'],
          ]);
```

Comment: that is being generated at  the end of the file and chats code is in head will that work ?

Comment: as i mentioned i cnat take that before html tags as db values are coming in a loop and generating divs

Answer (score 0):

Use code as bellow, do not use ' marks before or end of PHP statement. If you use ' mark it will not work.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
            ['Target',    <?php echo $targetFromDatabase;?>],
            ['Achieved',      <?php echo $achievedFromDatabase;?>],
          ]);
```